# Adding GraphQL syntactical highlighting for code blocks

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I went to post a question on Stack Overflow and provided a code block of GraphQL code. I tried doing something like:

```` ```gql ... ``` ````

and

```` ```graphql ... ``` ````

to get some syntax highlighting and didn't get anything. Is it possible to add this to the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Isn't GraphQL just JSON?  https://graphql.org/learn/queries

Comment: @Max not quite. There's more to it than that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GraphQL isn't [on the list of supported languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md).

The [project couldn't find a maintainer, so support was dropped](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/1471#issuecomment-587288492):

> " joshgoebel commented on Feb 17
> Closing this issue for lack of activity. Any one who'd like to take what's here and step up and contribute a 3rd party language grammar, that would be awesome. :-)"

Stack Exchange [won't add it until the project adds support for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109).

Comment: Sounds like I have a possible hobby on my hands haha.

Comment: @triplethreat78, with over 13 thousand uses of the tag on Stack Overflow you could [ask on their meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphql) (which has no prior questions raised) if someone is interested in becoming a maintainer at GitHub; then once it's supported upstream you can ask here for a [tag:status-review] and with all the plumbing in place it should `Just Work`™.

Comment: I don't think SE currently wishes to use 3rd party grammars though, so that is a bummer.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402607/will-stack-overflow-consider-supporting-third-party-highlight-js-packages

Comment: @Rob *"GraphQL isn't on the list of supported languages."* - It is now.

Comment: Until it's updated there's a [Chrome plugin](https://github.com/joshgoebel/se_highlightjs) available. Apparently [we are at 11.5.1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379238/282094), but 11.8.0 would be better. As mentioned in the FAQ, just ask for it; at MSE.