# Syntax highlighting changes in the middle of a token; resolved in a later version of Highlight.js

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, third-party

The code in [my answer over at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72096979/3840170) highlights very strangely:

> [image: The identifier ‘NodeRSA’ changes colour in the middle]

I discovered this at Stack Overflow, but it affects just as much all other Stack Exchange sites with highlighting enabled (I checked *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)*).  I don’t know if this is specific to JavaScript or affects anything else; I remember something similar happening before, but this is the only test case I have got at the ready.

Note that when using the latest version of Highlight.js (11.5.1), this does not happen:

[image: same code with new version of highlight.js]

So this is matter of outdated third party tool used by Stack Exchange to highlight code (version 11.0.1).

Comment: The highlighting used is probably javascript. That said this is caused by the third party tool SE uses for highlighting (highlight js). So therefore this is off-topic here and should reported with them.

Comment: @Luuklag The bug isn't present in latest highlight.js: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxO4v.png, SO is just out of date... as always.

Comment: @Nick yeah, taking long time for SE to adopt, or upgrade, but that can't be helped. I'm going to edit your comment into the bug report though, to keep it from being closed.

Comment: @Justin why did you remove my edit? This is relevant to the bug report. Please don't remove it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar: I didn't mean to. I was already editing the post before you :) Saving the edit must have removed your edit..

Comment: @Justin weird, usually there's a banner warning about it, though it doesn't block submitting the edit, yeah.

Comment: Related: *[Are JavaScript syntax highlighting colours random?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378456/are-javascript-syntax-highlighting-colours-random#comment1263332_378456)*

Comment: It also has [problems with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852102/css-scroll-snap-get-active-item#comment127489926_66852102). Though it could be for a different reason.

Comment: Why would these kind of questions be [closed as off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378456/)? 1) Stack Overflow the company could choose to change to ***another*** syntax highlighter (they already [did it once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/)), 2) change the ***version*** in use, and/or 3) change the way it is being ***implemented*** (for example, due to its buggy nature, ***turn it off*** by default (*explicit* syntax highlighting hints required) or greatly limit the places where it is applied).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum it's a gray zone, since it's third party tool. Bugs in the tool itself can't be fixed by SE, so strictly speaking, off topic. Replacing to different tool should be asked as new feature request, not part of bug report.

Comment: *Bugs in the tool itself can't be fixed by SE* — yes, they can. SE can patch the library and vendor it, or push the patch upstream. This is making excuses for laziness.

Comment: As per [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/241919), it's unlikely that SE will develop the patch. SE may only update the version used here, that's all.

Comment: Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431819/regular-expression-for-gst-identification-number-gstin/51742206#51742206) of weird syntax highlighting (change of colour ***in the middle*** of an identifier (*ValidateGSTIN*), a function call). (The code has an explicit syntax highlighting hint, "lang-javascript".)

Comment: Both the last example and the CSS example seem to have been fixed now (2022-07-02). Though there is a residual error [with `-ms-overflow-style`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852102/css-scroll-snap-get-active-item#comment128653444_66852102).

Comment: The implementation part is *huge* (*how* the library ***is used***). Stack Overflow has a lot of influence here. Some examples for illustration: 1) turn it off by default, and 2) turn it on for tags where it is known to work well (positive list). Or alternatively, using negative lists: Selectively turn it off where it is known to not work well, like for command lines, like Bash and other shells, or regular expressions.

Comment: More examples for CSS: [Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184958/add-space-between-html-elements-only-using-css/8185346#8185346), near "`first-child`". It *seems* [to be syntactically correct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child), though I am not 100% sure. [Sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184958/add-space-between-html-elements-only-using-css/26930629#26930629), near "`first-of-type`". Perhaps it has a general problem with dashes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, we've updated [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) from version 11.3.1 to version 11.5.1. This fixes the bug in your answer:
[image: a screenshot of the code referenced in the meta question, but this time the highlighting correctly highlights the NodeRSA name]

I'm not sure why the version string said 11.0.1 before. When I ran `hljs.versionString` it said 11.0.1 in the browser, but the files we served were 11.3.1. In any case, we're at the latest version now!